# Encrypting full disk and restore data 16.04

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I need to fully encrypt my laptop as it is now a requirement with the customer data that I will be handling. I have been going through a lot of the posts on this topic, and it seems to be quite difficult to do post install of Ubuntu.

As I would rather not break anything while trying to get it done bit-by-bit, is it possible to take some sort of a system image/full disk backup, so I can use it to restore everything to the same state after reinstalling Ubuntu this time with full disk encrytion on from the start?

Also putting up a screenshot of my disk utility software in case that might be useful. I can see that it is split into :

- /boot
- /boot/efi
- LVM volume

Maybe can I just encrypt the LVM volume, would that be enough?

[Disk utility screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOxiG.png)

Comment: would doing it like this be an acceptable solution? : 1.) do encrypted ubuntu instalation + updates&reboot + graphics driver& reboot + basic sofware you need. 2.) use fillezilla to clone entire drive to a backup hard drive and repeat step two for every new save you need

Comment: @tatsu i considered something like that, found that there is someting called clonezilla, but I did not know if restoring a cloned image would mess with system files, since they were not encrypted in the original image

Comment: clonezilla doesn't do some "imaging" or other, it is a really powerfull tool because it is the dumbest approach you could possibly have have to cloning : it copies bit by bit... Formatting gets crushed and replaced with the new disk. this does not generate a file you can move arround it **is** the hard drive. if you clonzilla a 256GB disk with an ubuntu installed to it to a terabyte one your terabyte drive will have 256GB of formatted space with all the rest of  the bits left at 0. It also copies over the drives master boot record. there is no way to tell the two clones appart.

Comment: basically, you do not have to worry about not being able to boot or any other encryption related issue with this solution. Just know that it is the "slow" solution. you have to Clonezilla to make a save and you have to Clonezilla to restore that save (yes repeat the exact same process but with the two drives inverted).

Comment: @tatsu just to make sure, if I use clonezilla to clone my entire disk to an external drive, format and reinstall ubuntu with encryption enabled on my laptop, use clonezilla to copy data from the external drive to my laptop, it would be like exactly the original, but with full disk encryption?

Comment: nope. what? why is that what you glean from what I said? you would have to make an ubuntu install with encryption and clonezilla **that**. When you want to restore it you don't need to format or anything since clonezilla cloning effectively formats the drive it's cloning to while cloning the data. So you'd just grab you external drive with that encrypted ubuntu clone on it and use clonezilla to place it where the current encrypted ubuntu that you're booting to is.

Comment: umm that literally doesnt help me at all in my current situation or my query with using something like clonezilla. I currently do not have an encrypted installation and i want to backup my current data as-is, not start over. If I did install a fresh copy, I would lose all the data and system setup i have done on my machine...

Comment: I don't know how much that is worth. it really wouldn't take long to do all this again. there is a shorter solution if you made `\home` a seperate partition durring install, did you do this? you could also, after having installed the dependencies you have that are apt packages, just move over home to a new install to move over most of the programs and settings.